# ASP.NET Application Deployment Question

Tags: asp.net, deployment

I'm creating an asp.net application/plug-in to run on a asp.net website/e-commerce solution. I want to make deployment easy for the user so that all they have to do is double click on an icon and all of my apps files will be placed into the proper folders on their asp.net website and all the necessary third-party files, like Microsoft's Visual Fox Pro 9 dll, will be installed. Is there a good tutorial or reference I can view to learn how to handle these deployment issues and are they even possible?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make an MSI (Microsoft Installer) which will do most of the work for them.

From *[Programming Microsoft ASP.NET 3.5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735625271)* by Dino Esposito

> Precompilation for deployment creates
>   a file representation of the site made
>   of assemblies and static files. This
>   representation can be generated on any
>   machine, and it can be packaged to MSI
>   and deployed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an MSI is definitely a good
   option to do this.
2. If you already have all the output
   with dependencies, then a batch copy
   script can do that for you.
3. If you are building from your
   source, then take a look at
   MsBuild/NAnt,and you can moidfy some
   post-build script to do that batch
   process for you.
4. You can also take a look at [web
   deployment project](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/28/vs-2008-web-deployment-project-support-released.aspx).