# ASP.NET Deployment

Tags: asp.net

I have developed an ASP.NET Website in Visual Studio 2008. Now I want to deploy that in some other machine. How can I do that?? Like we make an installation package for Windows application what can we do for ASP.NET Websites?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider using the [Web Deployment Tool](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/346/web-deployment-tool/) from Microsoft.  It was specifically designed to help deploy web applications and updates to those web applications to production IIS 6 and 7 web servers and it does a better job of the task than MSI (Windows Installer), IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

You should precompile it first.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227972.aspx

I use the web deployment projects, precompile and upload.

like this http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/28/vs-2008-web-deployment-project-support-released.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can create an MSI (Microsoft Installer) file which will create the structure on another machine. I've covered this in a very similar question a few days ago.

Edit: See this link [ASP.NET Application Deployment Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761725/asp-net-application-deployment-question/761727)

Answer (score 1):

Xcopy

"Xcopy-style file transfer simplifies the deployment and the maintenance of ASP.NET sites because you make no registry entries and because you register no components. The Microsoft .NET applications are self-describing, typically with no dependencies. With assembly versioning, you can even copy a new copy of a DLL that the application uses without stopping the Web server."

The above option of creating MSI is also good if you have a hand-over to operations to deploy on multiple machines.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you upload the files to the server, making sure that:

The destination folder is configured as an ASP.Net application folder
The web.config file is not configured to work with debugging anymore
The database is uploaded as well, and/or reachable by the application

(Anyways that's how I do it. Might exist a better solution, but it works.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Web Deployment Projects. How to is explained [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/11/06/429723.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

[VS 2008 Web Deployment Project](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/28/vs-2008-web-deployment-project-support-released.aspx)